# Search field in Django Template

Tags: django, search, django-templates, field

Search field in Django Template

How to create search field in Django Template similar to this image

http://asciicasts.com/system/photos/1204/original/E354I01.png

I try this in github
https://github.com/rg3915/vendas/commit/e0c67fd8154a3b8e450ec3db38705cdd7efc1350

But i do not know how to finish.

Comment: What do you see now? Which url/view are you calling? What have you tried already?

Answer (score 23):

You're talking about **search field** but essentially is just a **form**, you have an input (*the search box*) and you receive that input in your view.

Little example to manage forms and GET actions:

**views.py:**

```
def your_view(request):
    ''' This could be your actual view or a new one '''
    # Your code
    if request.method == 'GET': # If the form is submitted

        search_query = request.GET.get('search_box', None)
        # Do whatever you need with the word the user looked for

    # Your code
```

**template**

In your template, the most important thing for this is the form, you should have something like this:

```
# Your template code
<form type="get" action="." style="margin: 0">
    <input  id="search_box" type="text" name="search_box"  placeholder="Search..." >
    <button id="search_submit" type="submit" >Submit</button>
</form>
# Your template code
```

- `action='.'`  <-- This tells django to do the GET action in the same URL as you are
- `action='/other/url/'` <-- This tells django to do the GET in that URL
- This form is just an HTML form, you can use also [Django Forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/)

**urls.py**

Your URL file has to be the same you had before. You don't need to do any change to your actual URL, it should be something like:

```
url(r'^your_url/?$', 'yourproject.views.your_view', name='your_url_name'),
```

---

Anyway I recommend you to check some information like:

- [Django: Working with forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/)
- [Django Forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/)
- [Django Tutorial forms](http://tutorial.djangogirls.org/django_forms/README.html)

Comment: its is dont work https://github.com/rg3915/vendas/commit/27f9f305b45bf78a9944b263df0d9d89ae475354

Comment: I resolved https://github.com/rg3915/vendas/commit/fdce9ecbfef6fd6a94f5ba00d7622f34ddaa2ff0

Answer (score 3):

Frontend: Template

create a form with a search box(using html ,css)

```
<form type="get" action="exact_url" > 
    <input  id="search_box" type="text" name="search_box"  placeholder="Search..." > 
    <button id="search_submit" type="submit" >Submit</button> 
</form>
```

**Backend**: *View*

- write a funtion in **views.py**
- Search | Django documentation | Django (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/search/#search) use it writing query
- the jsonresponse can be rendered using template language Templates | Django documentation | Django (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/templates/#the-django-template-language)
- write a query using __contains

  ```
     def your_view(request):
        if request.method == GET:  
            search_text = request.GET.get(search_box", None)
            records=Table.objects.filter(columnn__contains=search_text)     
            from django.http import JsonResponse
            return JsonResponse({"result_records":records})
  ```
- your url should be same as in **form(template) **and your_view should be same as in views.py (**View**)

  ```
     url(r'^exact_url/?$', 'yourproject.views.your_view')
  ```